# Shorthand-if with character index check

Tags: javascript, shorthand-if

I am using a shorthand if statement to check if content has an italic tag in it.

```
remove = (content.indexOf('<i>') === true) ? true : false;
alert("ORIGINAL CONTENT: " + content + "\nDoes content contain <i>? " + remove);
```

When that alert pops up, it shows the following:
[Alert box shows < i > in string, but returns false](http://photostand.co.za/images/c8rohscblnz82rzmhxij.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the purpose of `bla === true ? true : false` when you can also write `bla === true`? If you don't get it, your code now looks like `true ? true : false`.

Comment: I give remove another value. I just eventually put in true or false to see why it's giving the wrong result. But your comment is 100% true, so I gave it an up vote. EDIT TO ADD: This is what happens eventually: `(content.indexOf('<i>') !== -1) ? '' : content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the position of the string inside another string, and -1 if it's not found. It's not like `strpos` in PHP. So you have to check `content.indexOf('<i>') !== -1` instead.

In your case, I'd simply define

```
remove = content.indexOf('<i>') !== -1;
```

The ternary operator (I used to know that by this name) isn't really necessary here, as the comparison already gives the boolean value you need.

Comment: Side note: Ternary operator just means "an operator with three operands". I prefer to use the term conditional operator, as it describes what the operator actually does. :)

Comment: @MaxArt, thanks for the answer. I often get mixed up with PHP and Javascript/jquery when it comes to if's etc. Don't know why... Anyhow, works perfectly now.

Comment: @MaxArt—it's actually a **ternary expression** and uses the [conditional operator ?:](http://es5.github.com/#x11.12).

Comment: @Guffa "Conditional operator" is fine too. I know that "ternary" means something else, but there's actually only one in Javascript...

Comment: @RobG It's a ternary operator anyway. I don't think anyone will get confused by that, as long as there's just one ternary operator in so many programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Regex?

```
remove = /<i>/.test(content);
```

Thanks RobG for the correction.

Comment: You have that backwards, test is a method of regular expressions, not strings: `/<i>/.test(content)`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly covered in other answers, but in:

```
> content.indexOf('<i>') === true
```

note that [String.prototype.intexOf](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.7) returns a Number and it is being compared to a Boolean. Since they are different Types, the result will always be false. If the equals operator "==" had been used, it would return true if the left hand expression returned any value other than zero (0).

Incidentally, italic text can be implemented using elements other than I, e.g. a span element with suitable styling applied through CSS.